# How to reset unit test?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have an unit test that look like this:

```
describe('myDirective:', function () {

    var rootScope, compile;

    beforeEach(module('myApp'));

    beforeEach(function () {
        //inject dependencies
        inject(function ($compile, $rootScope) {
            rootScope = $rootScope;
            compile = $compile;
        });
    });

    it('first test', function () {
        var scope = rootScope.$new();
        var element = angular.element('<my-directive><div id="myid" style="height:300px"></div></my-directive>');
        element.appendTo(document.body);
        element = compile(element)(scope);
        console.log("#myid height: "+$("#myid").height());
        expect($("#myid").height()).toBe(300);
    });

    it('second test', function () {
        var scope = rootScope.$new();
        var element = angular.element('<my-directive><div id="myid" style="height:400px"></div></my-directive>');
        element.appendTo(document.body);
        element = compile(element)(scope);
        console.log("#myid height: "+$("#myid").height());
        expect($("#myid").height()).toBe(400);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bLg4veso/

It pass the `first test`, but fail on `second test`. The `second test` will always return the height as being set in the `first test`. How can I reset it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are appending the element to the body, you need to manually remove it too.

Add this line to end of each test

`element.remove();`

and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could use the `afterEach()` function available in Jasmine. It seems to be equivalent to `tearDown()` from Python's `unittest` module, in that `afterEach()` is executed after each test.

By using the `afterEach()` function, you only have to specify this clean up work once.

You can read more about `afterEach()` (as well as similar functions like `beforeEach()`, etc) on [Jasmine's introduction documentation page](http://jasmine.github.io/2.4/introduction.html#section-Setup_and_Teardown).